# Changing user log in from Email to Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5, by default the login and register setup comes with Email and Password. I want to instead use username and password. There are number of similar cases posted here but following them doesn't help. When I try to register, I get the error message saying "Email can't be null." It seems the setup for email is still valid somewhere and am not sure where. Changes I have made to user Username instead of Email as follows':

AccountViewModel

```
//Removed Email and added username for RegisterViewModel 

public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Accountcontroller change email to username at Register

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   //changed email to username
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username};
        //var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);                    
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
```

Register.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I would do the same for login upon understanding what step I am missing.

Comment: Trace it in the debugger and see where the error is coming from.  There's usually at least 3 layers that the validation could be in (e.g. View, Model, Entity).

Comment: I have used breakpoints on the files I have changed. Nothing shows up. IT is not an exception and instead shows a string thus the exception is caught somewhere. The exact string is "Email cannot be null or empty". Tried to search using find an the string does not show up either on the common files. guess I gotta go file by file.

Comment: UserManager is still looking for an email which as you commented it out makes sense. Require the email for registering but not login.

Comment: @ShawnC How do I make it not a requirement for registering? Cos I tried removing that comment and also placing back Email at AccountViewModel, leave out Email field at View -- and same error message when I try to register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess so please be kind.

In your startup you configure the AddIdentity.

Something like this is most likely there:

```
// Add Identity services to the services container.
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Change it to

```
  // Add Identity services to the services container.
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false; })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This is based on the assumption of using EF and https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserValidator.cs#L55

Comment: where is this file? You mentioned startup as in  App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs ?